# Electric guitar noise gate pedal

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal, noise

I’m new to electric guitar stuff. I am interesting about a noise gate pedal to reduce the noise of my amp. I do not use a pedal for over-drive. Instead I use amp’s over-drive channel.

Since I do not have an over-drive pedal I need to know, that the noise gate pedal work only with the guitar input and output to the amp or does it have to input through the over-drive pedal?

Answer (score 3):

A noise gate cannot reduce the noise of your amp.  Basically the theoretical best you can manage is getting to the noise level with nothing plugged in (strictly speaking, the noise level when plugging in a plug that has been short-circuited, but that should usually be similar).

If it's the amp producing the noise, anything that you put before the amp will produce at least as much noise as leaving the amp without input.

If the amp has an "effect loop" out/input, putting your noise gate there might be effective.  If you have a separate over-drive brick, it needs to get wired before any noise gate to be effective: overdrives tend to work as mostly linear amplifiers at high gain setting for small signals, so they are likely to produce/amplify noise.

Note that a noise gate can in some situations act more distracting than constant noise.  You just have to try.